# Codeigniter Image resize issue

Tags: codeigniter, image-resizing

I can't re-size a large uploaded image into tow copies one in another size and the other is in another size.

I can only resize only one image.

What I want to ask is. I want to creat a thumbnail as well as slighter larger image of a user profile photo.

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profilepic']['tmp_name'], './profile_pix/'. $profile_pic_name1)){
                        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                        $config['source_image'] = './profile_pix/'. $profile_pic_name1;
                        $config['create_thumb'] = false;
                        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                        $config['width'] = 150;
                        $config['height'] = 190;
                        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                        $this->image_lib->resize(); 

                        $thumb_name = './profile_pix/thumb_'.$profile_pic_name1;
                        copy('./profile_pix/'. $profile_pic_name1, $thumb_name);

                       $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                        $config2['source_image'] = $thumb_name;
                        $config2['create_thumb'] = false;
                        $config2['maintain_ratio'] = false;
                        $config2['width'] = 50;
                        $config2['height'] = 50;
                        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config2);
                        $this->image_lib->resize();
                   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your image library is already loaded. so call the `initialize()` function instead of `load()`